# Git Diff Tool setting in Visual Studio 2019 16.10.3 not working

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, winmerge

Since updating VS2019 to version 16.10.3, I can't get "Compare with Unmodified..." to use WinMerge as my Diff Tool.  In my global '.gitconfig' I've got:

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool "Winmerge"]
    cmd = "'C:\\Program Files\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe'" -e "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

In the 'Git' - 'Settings' -  'Git Global Settings' options page, under Tools, it shows:

```
Diff Tool: winmerge | Global | Use Visual Studio
```

but 'winmerge' and 'Global' are greyed out. When I select a file in 'Git Changes' and click "Compare with Unmodified...", it uses VSDiff. Diff'ing a file in a TFS controlled solution uses WinMerge, as expected. I have tried adding the settings shown above to the local '.git\config' file as well, but I get the same greyed out 'winmerge' under 'Git' - 'Settings' -  'Git RepositorySettings' - 'General'. The 'Tools' - 'Options...' - 'Source Control' - 'Plug-in Selection' is set to "Git".

I'm sure I had this working at one time (before VS2019 upgrade), but now I can't get it to work. I have tried the suggestions from several other questions on 'Diff' and 'Merge' using git version control, but I am overwhelmed by the number of solutions, and none of them have worked. What am I missing?

Comment: I am also having this problem with BeyondCompare

Comment: @JNygrenLT did you get it to work? having the same issue with KDIFF

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange, but I have experienced that closing a file in Visual Studio before doing "Compare with unmodified" can help.